# Initiating YouTube Live Streams on Android

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I want to stream a video from my Android application on Youtube but I want to stream a Stream not just give the Camera to the Youtube api and let it fo the job, I want create a stream by myself so that I can modify it first and add some effects on the video, then convert it to a stream, then stream it.

I am ok with the first part, the stream is ready, modified, filtered, effects are added. How to stream that stream to Youtube from Android?